# Definition of cosinus: Taylor series vs. right-triangle

Tags: trigonometry, taylor-expansion, triangles

Is it possible to give a formal proof that the definition of cosinus by a series is the same as done in geometry using right triangles? If the answer is yes, then please give the proof here.

Comment: Probably. Otherwise they most likely wouldn't have the same name.

Comment: The meat of such a proof would just be proving the derivatives of sine and cosine, from there it would just be a matter of using Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Yes, thank you!